# Short time str not displaying correctly

Tags: php

I'm using the following function to display time:

```
date('g:i A', strtotime($time))
```

If `$time` is a `4 digit integer`, like `1430` the time shows correctly as `2:30 PM`. However if the if it's before `10am`, say `8am`, the time string is `800` and the function shows it as `12:00 am`.

I cannot edit time value in my db. How can I fix it on a PHP side?

Thanks.

Comment: *the time string is 800 and the function shows it as 12:00 am.* which function ?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it incorrectly. Updated.

Comment: post your complete code. We can't make assumption

Comment: You need to convert the "time string" in to something that `strtotime()` accepts, as detailed on the [time formats manual page](http://php.net/datetime.formats.time).  [cvipul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46285522/113938) is a fair start.

Comment: @salathe I already convert it using strtotime().

Comment: *\*facepalm\** ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pad the integer value you are storing in $time with zeroes

Use either of the below functions :

```
$formatted_time = sprintf("%04d", $time);
```

OR

```
$formatted_time = str_pad($time, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Use this value as input to the strtotime function.

Comment: I know it will work, because I tried adding a manual value like "0800" for 8 am, but it looks a bit over-engineered. AlsoI don't need to pad strings that are already 4 chars long

Comment: @santa `strtotime()` has no way to know the hour is represented on 1 or 2 digits, that's why you should always provide it 4 digits. Even more, to make sure it doesn't interpret them as something else (`1942` could be `7:42 PM` but it can also be a year) you better use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It still needs 4 digits but it will never interpret `1942` as a year if it's given the correct format specifier (`'i:s'`).

Comment: @santa Well, you edited the question within the time it took me to answer. 
But even if you are looking for something better, doesn't mean this is irrelevant. Downvote seems pretty harsh.
str_pad function will not pad strings that are already 4 digits long.

Comment: I did not down vote. Even if it's not a solution I'll pick, I always appreciate any help I can get. I'll upvote it to keep it at zero at least.

Comment: I've implemented this solution. It works, case closed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pop an instance of DateTime() and define your timezone and set a timestamp

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"))->setTimestamp(800);
```

[3v4l.org/iLk57](https://3v4l.org/iLk57)